# NxN matrix is given and we have to find

Tags: dynamic-programming

N things to select for N people, you were given a NxN matrix and cost at each element, you needed to find the one combination with max total weight, such that each person gets exactly one thing.

I found difficulty in making its dp state.
please help me and if possible then also write code for it

Comment: At stackoverflow no one will solve your homework. At least try it and post the code and ask questions based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

C++ style code:

```
double max_rec(int n, int r, int* c, double** m, bool* f)
{
    if (r < n)
    {
        double max_v = 0.0;
        int max_i = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (f[i] == false)
            {
                f[i] = true;
                double value = m[r][i] + max_rec(n, r + 1, c, m, f);
                if (value > max_v)
                {
                    max_v = value;
                    max_i = i;
                }
                f[i] = false;
            }
        }
        c[i] = max_i;
        return max_v;
    }
    return 0.0;
}

int* max_comb(int n, double** m)
{
    bool* f = new bool[n];
    int* c = new int[n];
    max_rec(n, 0, c, m, f);
    delete [] f;
    return c;
}
```

Call `max_comb` with N and your NxN matrix (2d array). Returns the column indices of the maximum combination.

Time complexity: O(N!)
I know this is bad but the problem does not have a greedy structure.

And as @mszalbach said, try to attempt the problem yourself before asking.

EDIT: can reduce to polynomial time by memoizing.